# Conditional elements in -> / ->> pipelines

Tags: clojure

Given a `->>` pipeline like so:

```
(defn my-fn []
  (->> (get-data)
       (do-foo)
       (do-bar)
       (do-baz)))
```

I wish to make the various stages conditional.

The first way of writing this that came to mind was as such:

```
(defn my-fn [{:keys [foo bar baz]}]
  (->> (get-data)
       (if foo (do-foo) identity)
       (if bar (do-bar) identity)
       (if baz (do-baz) identity))
```

However, as the `->>` macro attempts to insert into the `if` form, this not only looks unfortunate in terms of performance (having the noop `identity` calls), but actually fails to compile.

What would an appropriate, reasonably DRY way of writing this be?

Comment: Does `get-data` return a sequence as is usually used with `->>`?  Are the `do-` function calls side-effects, or taking/returning something?

Comment: It seems unlikely that the if in the threaded call will hurt performance in any appreciable way

Comment: @AlexTaggart Yes, `get-data` returns a sequence -- potentially a quite long one, making this effectively an inner loop. The `do-*` functions are pure, having no side effects; perhaps I named the code in the example poorly.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Arthur is correct regarding performance. The branch checking will be optimized away rather quickly.

Comment: @AlexTaggart I'm actually more concerned about the identity calls than about the branch.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Modern Clojure (that is, as of 1.5) supports a variety of options for conditional threading, but you probably want `cond->>`.

### conditional threading with `cond->` and `cond->>`

Clojure offers [`cond->`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cond-%3E) and [`cond->>`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cond-%3E%3E), which each ask for a set of pairs: a test and an expression if that test evaluates to true. These are quite similar to `cond` but don't stop at the first true test.

```
(cond->> 5
  true inc
  false inc
  nil inc)
=> 6
```

Your specific example is probably best written like so:

```
(defn my-fn [{:keys [foo bar baz]}]
  (cond->> (get-data)
    foo (do-foo)
    bar (do-bar)
    baz (do-baz)))
```

### as->

It's worth mentioning [`as->`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/as-%3E) because it is perhaps the most versatile threading macro. It gives you a name to refer to the "thing" being threaded through the forms. For instance:

```
(as-> 0 n
  (inc n)
  (if false
    (inc n)
    n))
=> 1

(as-> 0 n
  (inc n)
  (if true
    (inc n)
    n))
=> 2
```

This gives substantial flexibility when working with a mix of functions that require threading the expression at different points in the parameter list (that is, switching from -> to ->> syntax). One should avoid the use of extraneous named variables in the interest of code readability, but oftentimes this is the clearest and simplest way to express a process.

Comment: though `as->` is the most versatile, IMO `cond->` is the most appropriate for the OPs requirement

Comment: @Andy you're totally right, not sure why I missed that. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 12):

This works too:

```
(defn my-fn [{:keys [foo bar baz]}]
  (->> (get-data)
       (#(if foo (do-foo %) %))
       (#(if bar (do-bar %) %))
       (#(if baz (do-baz %) %)) ))
```

Answer (score 9):

You might be interested in these macros https://github.com/pallet/thread-expr

Comment: +1 for suggesting not to reinvent the wheel. :) I've used your thread-expr library and it's simple, small, elegant and works fine.

Comment: Are you proposing `(when-> foo do-foo)`, or a different usage?

Answer (score 6):

you can fix the compiling part (though not the ascetic part by having the **if statement decide which function to run** by putting another set of `( )` as so:

```
(defn my-fn [{:keys [foo bar baz]}]
  (->> (get-data)
   ((if foo do-foo identity))
   ((if bar do-bar identity))
   ((if baz do-baz identity)))
```

would expand into a series of calls like this:

```
   ;  choose function         and call it    
   ( (if foo do-foo identity) args       )
   ( (if bar do-bar identity) args       )
   ( (if baz do-baz identity) args       )
```

Comment: Thanks! I had been quoting my fns, ie `((if foo 'do-foo 'identity) args)` - your example helped me debug my issue!

Answer (score 5):

A more general way to go if you need this sort of thing often:

```
(defn comp-opt [& flag-fns]
  (->> flag-fns
    (partition 2)
    (filter first)
    (map second)
    (apply comp)))

(defn my-fn [{:keys [foo bar baz]}]
  (map (comp-opt foo do-foo
                 bar do-bar
                 baz do-baz)
       (get-data)))
```